# Why clojure swap! does not work properly with map?

Tags: clojure

```
(defn get-vector []
    (let [rs (atom [])]
        (map (fn [x] (swap! rs conj x)) [1 2 3 4]) 
      @rs))

(get-vector)
```

I think this function should return `[1 2 3 4]`;
however, it just returns an empty vector `[]`.

Answer (score 10):

Clojure `map` is lazy and as you are not asking for its result it doesn't evaluate its contents and doesn't execute your function with `swap!`.

To get it working you should force it to realise its contents using `dorun`:

```
(defn get-vector []
  (let [rs (atom [])]
    (dorun (map (fn [x] (swap! rs conj x)) [1 2 3 4]))
    @rs))

(get-vector)
;; => [1 2 3 4]
```

I am not sure what problem you are trying to solve - if this is just a sample code to test how `swap!` works than that code looks OK. Otherwise you might want to use another solutions like `reduce` and avoid mutable reference.

As suggested by @Shlomi, it would be more idiomatic to use `doseq` for side effects:

```
(let [rs (atom [])]
  (doseq [x [1 2 3 4]]
    (swap! rs conj x))
  @rs)
```

Comment: I'd also note that `map` is not idiomatic clojure for side effects, for that we have [`doseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq)

Comment: Yes, you are right. It would be better to use `doseq` for such scenario. Let me enhance the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`doseq` is more idiomatic, but I prefer the syntax of `map`, so another option is to create a `maprun` which forces the sequence to realize:

```
(def maprun (comp dorun map))

(defn get-vector []
  (let [rs (atom [])]
    (maprun (fn [x] (swap! rs conj x)) [1 2 3 4]) 
    @rs))

(get-vector)
```

This is technically the same as Piotrek's, as `maprun` is merely syntactic sugar.

Comment: Unnecessary, because this function, named [`run!`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/run!), is already part of the core library.